# Creating Drools .drl files programmatically

Tags: drools

I have a requirement to generate drools drl files programmatically based on a service response from an external system. What is the recommended way to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an internal API to programmatically create rules in Drools, but it's not stable and it is not documented at all.

Usually, a template engine is enough. If your rules all share the same structure, you could also consider a to create a decision table on an spreadsheet.

Hope it helps,